# How to force fields in advanced search to have reasonable width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

In advanced search dialog, all search field have width of maximum field.

If there is wide search field which does not fit to search form and right justified numberic amount searc field, amount contants are not visible.

To reproduce, create wide editable note column using colmodel:

```
name: "note", 
width: 43, 
editoptions: {"maxlength":80,"size":80 }
```

And select amount and notes field in search form in small screen

[image: notv]

Amount field width is too big. Accessing its value requires scrolling.

Amount field should have its native width .
There is no need to create so wide Amount field.

How to fix this ?

I tried todays free jqgrid from github, but problem persists.
Testcase is in https://jsfiddle.net/kobruleht/wpyb50fj/

Comment: I'm understand the problem generally, but I don't understand the example. The settings `size:80` can't be good displayed in the searching dialog. Why you not just define `searchoptions: { maxlength: 80, size: 20 }` in the column like https://jsfiddle.net/wpyb50fj/1/ ? The structure of searching dialog is the table. On can easy reduce the width of input of amount, but other elements of the searching dialog will still look not nice. Thus reducing of width of the input of `note` searching field seems to me the only go solution *for the demo*.

Comment: Thank you. Using maxlength and size in searchoptions solves the issue.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. I posted the same information as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the most easy way to solve the problem would be to add

```
searchoptions: { maxlength: 80, size: 20 }
```

option. It allows to use long field for editing, but to hold the searching filed small. See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/wpyb50fj/1/.

The structure of searching dialog is the table. On can easy reduce the width of input of amount, but other elements of the searching dialog will still look not nice. Thus I don't see another solution of your problem, which will be easy enough.